# How to get max row_number per group/id in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

6806969 3
6806969 1
6806969 2
7654392 1
7654392 2
I have an Id and in next column has row_num value. How can I enter next value in table in such a way that for id 6806969 next inserted value must be 4 and for id 7654392 next inserted value must be 3. Please suggest any way. I tries max() with row_number but It is not giving me desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_id (id_key NUMBER)
DECLARE prev_max NUMBER
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX(row_num) INTO prev_max FROM your_table WHERE id = id_key;
   INSERT INTO your_table(id, row_num) VALUES (id, prev_max + 1); 
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
     prev_max := 1;
     INSERT INTO your_table(id, row_num) VALUES (id, prev_max + 1);
END;
```

And call it like that

```
BEGIN
   add_id(6806969);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I need to insert into the table with the help of one select statement. something like 'insert into table A(id,id_val) select id,next_max_value from table b'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single `INSERT` statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( id, row_num )
SELECT id, row_num + 1
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         row_num
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  id = :your_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT :your_id,
         0
  FROM   DUAL
  ORDER BY row_num DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=706b077f4c4789d2a223360b817d0f52)

Comment: currently I am using below query    INSERT INTO  OF_THTIERAPPROVERHISTORY
        (  SELECT DISTINCT AT.AT_TRANSACTION_K, 
        (SELECT (NVL(MAX(TH_SEQUENCEID_K), 0)+1) FROM OF_THTIERAPPROVERHISTORY WHERE TH_TRANSACTION_AH_K = AT_TRANSACTION_K) AS VALUE,
        TH_ROLEID, TH_USERID, TH_AUDITTEXT, TH_ACTDATETIMECTRY, TH_ACTDATETIMESRV 
        FROM 
         OF_THTIERAPPROVERHISTORY TH, OF_ATAVAILMENTTICKETS AT
        WHERE 
        AT.AT_TRANSACTION_K = TH.TH_TRANSACTION_AH_K (+)
          AND AT.AT_GROUP_ID = 27918  and AT.AT_TRANSACTION_K in(6806969,6806942) );

Comment: I am not sure how can i add row_num to it